# `Error: org.json.JSONException` for json parsing using volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to fetch json data using volley from google api. I am getting `Error: org.json.JSONException` in logcat. How do i solve it?

my Google Api url,

```
private String urlJsonObj = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=21.2150756,72.8880545&radius=500&type=hospital&key=AIzaSyBldIefF25dfjjtMZq1hjUxrj4T4hK66Mg";
```

`makeJsonObjectRequest` function for to fetch the data,

```
private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
showpDialog();

// Creating volley request obj
JsonArrayRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonObj,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                hidepDialog();

                try {
                    JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray(1);
                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = results.getJSONObject(i);
                            LocationDetailModel locationDet = new LocationDetailModel();
                            locationDet.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
                            locationDet.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("vicinity"));

                            LocationDetailList.add(locationDet);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                    // Do something to recover ... or kill the app.
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d( "VolleyError","Error: " + error.getMessage());
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        hidepDialog();

    }
});

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

}

I am getting bellow error in my logcat,

```
04-19 12:56:25.348 4485-4485/com.example.chaitanya.nearbyplace D/VolleyError: Error: org.json.JSONException: Value {"html_attributions":[],"results":[{"geometry":{"location":{"lat":21.21508679999999,"lng":72.8883554},"viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":21.2164357802915,"lng":72.8897043802915},"southwest":{"lat":21.21373781970849,"lng":72.88700641970848}}},"icon":"https:\/\/maps.gstatic.com\/mapfiles\/place_api\/icons\/doctor-71.png","id":"831a38ee464657c1b60683be963e145b566e95d1","name":"Deep Children Hospital","place_id":"ChIJE1cZjXpP4DsR1ITMcESvDeU","rating":4.2,"reference":"CmRSAAAApsEU5Kvy3RIGkxaQklHK-Jr700tF_DGu4JAEAEibQ-lVZQApAddzMtONETVQihcJ1MYooX0k5QRphjsplHb6xgALmefjoHiAc-O3N08_S5blHqRKVZogOeNCe6urVEaaEhAfVhJbsQvCY2dKrl5j8CfdGhSCsQtU2BuIGkWvMgRzVwf4oYziSQ","scope":"GOOGLE","types":["hospital","point_of_interest","establishment"],"vicinity":"302-305, Swastik Plaza, Pune- Simada Road, Yogi Chowk, Yogidarshan Society, Nana Varachha, Surat"},{"geometry":{"location":{"lat":21.2149842,"lng":72.8883906},"viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":21.2163331802915,"lng":72.88973958029149},"southwest":{"lat":21.2136352197085,"lng":72.88704161970848}}},"icon":"https:\/\/maps.gstatic.com\/mapfiles\/place_api\/icons\/doctor-71.png","id":"e62d17d2eaba8c7af64144418c845476837d0610","name":"Chirayu General Hospital","opening_hours":{"open_now":true,"weekday_text":[]},"place_id":"ChIJI_rAjHpP4DsRVfNqHtl8s24","reference":"CmRRAAAA6Sr99xxP0-2xzTjFP-ajIfr63ZtMMVCyz4xtAuV3y6CxvlsyQRUp5Lx35uc7-Ir7jafjCJPPQ0XBCy28QSqj8drtgZqhu-Pk6MAz--jG4RjdwdL1WQGzu3Pf_SEMIJMBEhBXQCMOtyY01AkUfLNSNe-rGhSjLdu_AbeYiW5cTp3xQbaYDsAO7A","scope":"GOOGLE","types":["hospital","point_of_interest","establishment"],"vicinity":"402-406 Swastik Plaza, Puna-Simada Road, Yogi Chowk Ground, Chikuwadi, Nana Varachha, Surat"},{"geometry":{"location":{"lat":21.213784,"lng":72.88569799999999},"viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":21.2151329802915,"lng":72.8870469802915},"southwest":{"lat":21.2124350197085,"lng":72.8843490197085}}},"icon":"https:\/\/maps.gstatic.com\/mapfiles\/place_api\/icons\/doctor-71.png","id":"c4290cb09a3be448718cd65ebc9a62c90799c2aa","name":"Vaghani Hospital","photos":[{"height":794,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https:\/\/maps.google.com\/maps\/contrib\/103410682498224690153\/photos\">Vaghani Hospital<\/a>"],"photo_reference":"CoQBdwAAAFzUTtvhGHzcYJq-UdYpzxRpMKlgSkkHtu87G8u3WD6s99wwxEnwGxUEcUSCRJDsSIM8veQVPKRkUkn1rFTCB4pPotitPXtxYIMQksBTvDvuAynm9sHzxJnf65RaSFJcJ_rMUJ9ghS4PeIF0SV_C2XZ5BCBwOgkD9tgCNmOxXrxSEhAMrcGa8Khzysiffh2Vo8CkGhT-ZGU78NmQcMC5trHSS1h3nNsp_g","width":794}],"place_id":"ChIJ13n1jHBP4DsRhVsMMvBHBrU","rating":4.8,"reference":"CmRSAAAAG-tPKgTwGveJEt0PL9IDIe9XLQkBnpZFJTsY0XDArF7jUT81szl_x7F1ndeOB3TZVsYcEEMf7G93CIuPs-fodpEjM413PI7Mb1IdlO5bTWGNBebPZoAyu9dPqGjJCM6yEhAyotMjeoI9Hyvr4PEb0vKjGhRbPbYmp-uwwdVyDapzxpV4pOMfXw","scope":"GOOGLE","types":["hospital","point_of_interest","establishment"],"vicinity":"434-445, 4 th Floor, Apple Square,, Beside Swastik Plaza, Yogi Chowk, Surat., Surat"},{"geometry":{"location":{"lat":21.2150921,"lng":72.8880922},"viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":21.2164410802915,"lng":72.88944118029151},"southwest":{"lat":21.21374311970849,"lng":72.88674321970849}}},"icon":"https:\/\/maps.gstatic.com\/mapfiles\/place_api\/icons\/doctor-71.png","id":"34d3977def7c2ee31d41db96d55df1b4c07c7e72","name":"Virdiya Hospital","place_id":"ChIJ5U12jnpP4DsRylJBztn0bdE","reference":"CmRSAAAAZefzhhlgAEYxBv29zBLtp_eLrZpy-RVAFzeVtpFrNGFoYPKQ6JQddoNUvGtTz2Ow10KHYJw7pajUHe9KhDBSM5lgaDRu9bNBMX1jCgjmZqq9MO3df_EpayVsFST5Jx6NEhA8jCjggaoVYu6rZnXcFy0eGhSiq_VX6gmNptn73kB1hNRZngIuxw","scope":"GOOGLE","types":["hospital","point_of_interest","establishment"],"vicinity":"315, 3rd Floor, Swastik Plaza, Yogi Chowk, Yogi Chowk Ground, Chikuwadi, Nana Varachha, Surat"},{"geometry":{"location":{"lat":21.2150999,"lng":72.88838419999999},"viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":21.2162783302915,"lng":72.88982628029149},"southwest":{"lat":21.2135803697085,"lng":72.88712831970848}}},"icon":"https:\/\/maps.gstatic.com\/mapfiles\/place_api\/icons\/doctor-71.png","id":"9469cd58c282297693fbc0cfe0cd25a1c34926a7","name":"Viradiya Test Tube Baby","
04-19 12:56:25.349 4485-4485/com.example.chaitanya.nearbyplace D/Volley: [1] override.onErrorResponse: ItemDetailsActivity
```

Comment: result arrayname --Json array name and Vicinty are jsonobject. If any doubts means ping me...

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray("results")` instead of `JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray(1)`

**Try this:**

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            hidepDialog();

            try {
                JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray("results");
                // Parsing json
                for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = results.getJSONObject(i);
                        LocationDetailModel locationDet = new LocationDetailModel();
                        locationDet.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
                        locationDet.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("vicinity"));

                        LocationDetailList.add(locationDet);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                // notifying list adapter about data changes
                // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                // Do something to recover ... or kill the app.
            }
        }

        ............
        ....................
```

Answer (score 0):

your API response is **json object** not **json array** so try to change **JsonArrayRequest** to  **JsonObjectRequest**